# How to shorten gap if a control is wanted to hide in IOS?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am showing a gallery view controller as shown in the first screenshot:
[image: Gallery control is shown]

If an item doesn't have more than one photo, gallery view is hidden.

[image: Galley control is hidden]

What I need is, shorten the whitespace gap between title and photo (where the gallery control is located) How can I do that?

Comment: You need to tell more about gallery view. And how are u making it display.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you show these elements.
You could just change the frame of the text part below the gallery to be gallery_height pixels taller.

```
CGRect frame = textpart.frame;
frame.origin = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y - gallery_height);
frame.size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height + gallery_height);
textpart.frame = frame;
```

"textpart" is whatever you call the view below the gallery

gallery_height is the height of the small gallery

Comment: You'll have to give some more information and code to better understand the situation.

How is your view structured? What type of view is the 'textpart'?